# How to inject http interceptor in service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

auth-interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor (private router : Router) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (localStorage.getItem('user') != null) {
        const clonedReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('user'))
        });
        return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
            tap(
                succ => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.status == 401) {
                        localStorage.removeItem('user');
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    }
    else {
        return next.handle(req.clone());
    }
}
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpBackend, HttpErrorResponse } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../model/user';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })   
 export class UserService {
serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/user';
 errorData = {};

 httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'x-access-token' localStorage.getItem('user')})
 };

 private http: HttpClient
 constructor(handler : HttpBackend) { 
  this.http = new HttpClient(handler)
 }

  addUser(formData) {
return this.http.post<User>(`${this.serverUrl}`, formData, 
 this.httpOptions).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
  );
 }

 getUser() {
return this.http.get<User>(`${this.serverUrl}`, this.httpOptions).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
  }
```

I want to inject http interceptor to service. I am confused how to inject it. I need it because i have done authentication using jwt token. if jwt token is provided then api will run that need to implemented in frontend too. I have used this auth.interceptor to set jwt token in header but i dont know how to inject it in service. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: i need it because i have done authentication using jwt token. if jwt token is provided then api will run that need to implemented in frontend too

Comment: You should keep that logic inside some service like AuthService

Comment: I have also provided service currently i am using http headers that's working fine. But what the use of http interceptor if we have to use http headers

Comment: You doesn't need to inject http interceptor service to get it work instead of that  you need to register it in your app module 's providers list like that 
`  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    UserService
  ]`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to inject http interceptor to service. I am confused how to
>   inject it.

In your `app.module.ts` add interceptors to the provider's array like below:~

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    AuthService, // get the token from here 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    UserService
  ]
})
```

In case you need to access AuthService in your AuthInterceptor to access the token, you have to inject it to the constructor of the AuthInterceptor and use it like below:~

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('Intercepted!', req);
    const authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    // something like this
    const copiedReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set(
        'authorization', 'Bearer ' + authService.token
      )
    });
    // Rest of the logic..
  }
}
```

(your AuthService might fetch the token and then you can add it to the localStorage, and then you can proceed with your implementation)

Sample JWT authentication [Working STACKBLITZ Demo App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwt-authentication-demo)

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Subham Sharma , the interceptor will fire before your service when an HTTP call is made the request gets bypassed to the interceptor, in case you need to inject any service to your interceptor you can do like how I have mentioned. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @Subham Sharma I've attached a sample JWT authentication as a STACKBLITZ demo app  in the answer you can have a look at the implementation. You may even reproduce your scenario as a [stackblitz app](https://www.stackblitz.com) so that we can figure out the issue.